# Confused in calculating the shortest-path using Dijkstra's Algorithm

Tags: algorithms, shortest-path

[image]

I am required to find the shortest path using Dijkstra's Algorithm. After performing the calculations, am I getting the following values correct?:

```
A=0
B=13
C=8
D=20
E=14
F=25
G=31
H=38
I=46
J=52
```

Comment: Program Dijkstra's algorithm and run it on your graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you only want to know the distance from A to a certain point, your first calculations are right. 
However A to H should be 37. Check that again.
Also, there are shorter paths from A to I and A to J. Just have a look again - the other values are correct.